# Ruby nil converted to_date

Tags: ruby, date, comparison

I am writing a little updater for a app that will update the last time someone logs in to the app and then saves it. its in rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3p327

```
def update_last_seen
  if current_account.present?
    if (Date.current - 1.day) > current_account.last_login_at
      current_account.last_login_at = Date.current
      current_account.save
    end
  end
end
```

I stuck that into the application controller and call it with a before filter. The only thing is that sometimes i have dates that are nil. so comparing date to nil gives errors. you cant call to_date on a nil.

```
nil.to_f => 0.0
nil.to_i => 0
nil.to_s => ""
nil.to_date => NoMethodError: undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass
"2013/07/26".to_date => Fri, 26 Jul 2013
```

how can i have it set it to be accepted as a blank date as it were.

i could always do

```
if current_account.last_login_at.blank? || (Date.current - 1.day) > current_account.last_login_at
```

that way it will set it if its not there but is there a semantic way of doing it?

UPDATE:

You might think this is has no point. the reason i ask is because there are some engines that have a nil for a date. for example excel will return dates two ways 1. as text as in `"06/12/2013"` or 2. an integer as the number of days from 01/01/1900. that date is excels `nil` date i was hoping that there was a default date for nils for Ruby. if there isn't you can just comment nope there isn't sorry man. giving a downvote without explanation as to why means that you really don't care about helping/teaching anything you're just there pushing buttons. if i did something wrong with this question you can tell me ill try fix it, if it doesnt make sence?

Comment: why two lines assign and save. Instead use update_attributes. `current_account.update_attributes(:last_login_at => Date.current)` This way you can avoid the extra explicit save call. The update_attributes will automatically call save. Check this http://maxivak.com/update_attribute-and-update_attributes-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: i like that. thanks that looks much nicer. good link as well

Comment: True, I'll update my answer - also, you shouldn't need to worry if you have `after_save` callbacks, as those get called for both create & update saves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add in another method to clean up the code a *little* bit.

```
def new_login_since?(last_login)
    last_login.blank? || (Date.current - 1.day) > last_login
end

def update_last_seen
  if current_account.present? && new_login_since?(current_account.last_login_at)
    current_account.update_attributes { last_login_at: Date.current }
  end
end
```

Comment: No problem - also, just saw your edit - if you're dealing with many different default 'nil' dates (ie: the one you mentioned from Excel), you could abstract nil date handling out to a service object. More info on those at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects?view=asciicast)

Comment: yeah thats exactly my issue. i am pulling in from multiple sources and the nil date thing is making things messy. service object i think would be the best solution. i am going through it now. guess tonight is going to be re-factoring night. haha

Comment: Service objects aren't hard to implement, and you'll sleep better for it :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question ... you can monkey-patch the `NilClass` like this

```
class NilClass
  def to_date
    Date.today
  end
end

nil.to_date  # => #<Date: 2013-09-26 ((2456562j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Of course, the accepted answer shows the better approach.